# Count of rows in DB with particular field value using GSI

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

So I have below rows in `DynamoDB` with example data. I want to find out the count in below format which means given a `file name` as input, output should be the `number of events of that file present in the DB`. Currently I have created a `GSI` on `eventId` as `rangekey`  and `filename` as `hashkey`. I am doing `query` and `pagination` to get the count but its very slow due to number of rows in millions. Is there any other faster way to do it since I need to find only the count and not individual items.

```
fileName BrandCode Eventid
ABC       123       30100
ABC       367       30100
ABC       891       30111
XYZ       456       40758
XYZ       298       40759
XYZ       296       30111
```

Basically a file can generate multiple events and each event can be split into multiple Brandcodes.

```
FileName Count of events

ABC      2

XYZ      3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get group by and count of millions of records in fastest way in dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75471575/how-to-get-group-by-and-count-of-millions-of-records-in-fastest-way-in-dynamodb)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you want to avoid doing a Query and paginating all of the data each time you need a count of the items. I explain in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75471720/7909676) how to overcome that by using DynamoDB Streams and an aggregation window to create an easy to query count item, which you can retrieve with a single `GetItem` call, which is fast and efficient.